# How can I avoid having my R script printed every time I run it?

Tags: r, r-faq

Suppose I have an R script:

```
library('nnet')    
something <- runif(50); 
print(something)
```

When I run this script from the command line, it prints:

```
> library('nnet')
> something <- runif(5); 
> print(something)
 [1] 0.04665518 0.93574275 0.96387299 0.07410239 0.92834019
```

I would like it to print only:

```
[1] 0.04665518 0.93574275 0.96387299 0.07410239 0.92834019
```

and I cannot figure out how to do this. sink("/dev/null") doesn't do anything, redirecting stderr manually doesn't do anything, and I can't find any useful information on this.

Comment: How are you running it "at the command line"? `Rscript foo.R` only prints what you want...

Comment: And within R `source("foo.R")` would normally not show anything of the script unless you ask it to via `source("foo.R", echo = TRUE)`. Please show us **exactly** what you are trying/doing.

Comment: Rscript seems to have been what I was missing. Other posts on SE and elsewhere run scripts with "R < foo.R", which is evidently not the way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Resolution is to run with Rscript, and not with R. Examples elsewhere (e.g. **[How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2151212)**), run scripts from the command line with

```
R --args args1 args2... < foo.R
```

running with

```
Rscript foo.R args1 args2 ...
```

produces only the output, and not the script. It's also a much cleaner way to run scripts.

Comment: +1 Minor point, "poorly done" is uncalled-for. R hasn't always had `RScript` & the Q&A you link to is over 3 years old now. I suspect the usage of `RScript` had not embedded itself in the psyche of many R users at that point. Note also that those examples were not answering your question - you don't want your script echoed, which is a different matter and it is wrong to criticise for a lack of precognitive skills.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Fair point. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @JohnDoucette Excellent John. I wish more users on [so] and the [tag:r] tag were as civic minded as you have been today.

Comment: Not sure if this is separate question: I was directed here when I was looking to turn *on* source echoing (like 'set -x' in bash) for Rscript -- I'm guessing the way to to do that is just to run `<srcfile.R R --vanilla`, unless there are other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Not an R user myself, but is this something that might be helpful to you?
[How can I run an 'R' script without suppressing output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959337/how-can-i-run-an-r-script-without-suppressing-output)

From the linked question:

> specify `print.eval` parameter set to `TRUE` if you want to get only the output (and not the commands). If you would need the commands too, you should set `echo` to `TRUE` (which implies setting `print.eval` to `TRUE`).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> source('myscript.R', print.eval = TRUE)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
source( 'path/name/filnam.R' , verbose=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

For running in the terminal directly:

```
R --slave --args dense 12 0.98 < foo.R
```

For running R script from Python:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["R --slave --args %s %d %.2f < /path/to/your/rscript/foo.R" % (, 12, 0.98) ], shell=True)
process.wait()
```

For running R script in terminal / command line and in the background, while suppress / avoid printing every line of the scripts and the output of the program, using [R CMD BATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619877/running-r-in-batch-mode-on-linux-output-issues) as follow:

```
R CMD BATCH--slave foo.R 2>&1  foo.out &
```

See also [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602900/running-r-scripts-or-commands-with-interpretor-in-unix-for-unix-layman)

Answer (score 2):

For RStudio IDE (Version 1.1.383) in Windows:

Pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** keys run entire script with echo (verbose)

Pressing **Ctrl+Shift+S**     keys run entire script without echo (non-verbose)

Comment: Upvoted because I was looking for the Ctrl+Shift+S shortcut. But, at least for RStudio version 2022.07.0, the shortcut for running the entire script with echo is **Ctrl+Alt+R**. The shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** only runs the current chunk.